# dual boot mac OS problems

Tags: dual-boot

So I did a dual boot on my Macbook Air, or at least I thought.

I partitioned the hard-drive and used Etcher to install Elementary from a flash drive.

The installation went well, except I cannot boot back into Mac OS; I tried using Grub to do it but nothing loads at start up to give me the option of either OS.

If there is anything I can do I would be so happy and grateful, this has me so frustrated and I was up til the wee hours of the morning trying to fix it. If anyone can help I would appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 1):

Start the MacBook with the Option (⌥) key pressed. The disk selection menu should appear shortly after you turn it on. You can then release the Option (⌥) key and select the appropriate disk on which the macOS is installed.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Comment: Ok I will try that; when I installed Elementary OS I chose my Mac OS partition to be the 'swap' partition, is that ok? Swap does not mess up the OS right?

Comment: You've wiped the Mac for sure.